# Regex Validation for "ABC-1234" in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

What would be the regex if I want the user to match."abc-1234"

So 3 letter (upper or lower) followed by 4 numbers...

Here's what I have so far (thanks a lot!) :

```
    if (id.matches("^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]{3}-[\\d]{4}$")) {
        this.id = id;
    } else { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Inventory ID must be in the "
            + "form of ABC-1234");
    }

}
```

Comment: This is wrong: `[A-Z][a-zA-Z]{3}`, it matches 4 letters, change it to `[A-Za-z]{3}`

Comment: Not errors, but there's no need to put `\\d` inside `[]`, and when using `matches()`, you don't need `^` and `$`. So, with correction suggested by @kordirko, you get `id.matches("[a-zA-Z]{3}-\\d{4}")`

Comment: Thanks @Andreas - worked perfectly! cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
if (id.matches("[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}")) {
    this.id = id;
} else { 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Inventory ID must be in the "
        + "form of ABC-1234");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Pattern` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) says (edited / in part)

> #### Predefined character classes
>
> ```
> \d    A digit: [0-9]
> ```
>
> #### POSIX character classes (US-ASCII only)
>
> ```
> \p{Lower}     A lower-case alphabetic character: [a-z]
> \p{Upper}     An upper-case alphabetic character:[A-Z]
> \p{Alpha}     An alphabetic character:[\p{Lower}\p{Upper}]
> ```

So you could use something like

```
if (id.matches("\\p{Alpha}{3}-\\d{4}")) {
```

Comment: @Seo-JunKoh Since you said "thank you" to all the answers, it would seem you find them all useful. You should click the up-arrow on any answer you find useful. The checkmark for accepting can only be used on one answer, and I think you chose right by accepting this one, but you can up-vote as many answers as you want (within daily limit). --- Welcome to StackOverflow. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Below reg exp matches 3 char followed by - then four digits

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern can be broken down in the following parts:

- `[A-Z]`
- `[a-zA-Z]{3}`
- `-`
- `[\\d]{4}`

In spoken language, this is: 1 uppercase letter plus 3 letters (which makes 4 in total) plus dash plus 4 digits.

Just replace the 3 with a 2, and it will work.

The resulting code will require that the first letter is uppercase. If you don’t want that, use one of the other answers.